# Submit Form in Bootstrap Modal with IronRouter / MeteorJS

Tags: javascript, forms, twitter-bootstrap, meteor, iron-router

I am trying to submit a new appetizer to a web app I am creating that resembles a cookbook.  The layout has a constant header/nav that allows the user to add a new appetizer, which triggers a modal and a form containing the appetizer name, description and a photo.  I would like the modal to close upon submission, and remain on the current page of which the modal was triggered.  Currently, my submit form is not working and I am not sure where the problem is...

The link to the current deployed version is: http://reed-cookbook.meteor.com/

My router:

```
// lib/router.js

Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate: 'layout'
});

Router.map(function() {
    this.route('allRecipes', {
        path: '/'
    });

    this.route('appetizers', {
        path: '/appetizers'
    });

    this.route('appetizerPage', {
        path: '/appetizers/:_id',
        data: function() { return Appetizers.findOne(this.params._id); }
    });

    this.route('desserts', {
        path: '/desserts'
    });

    this.route('mainCourses', {
        path: '/maincourses'
    });

    this.route('submit', {
        path: '/appetizerSubmit'
    });
});
```

My appetizer html form:

```
// client/views/forms/appetizerForm.html

<template name="appetizerForm">
    <!-- This is the appetizer modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myAppModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add An Appetizer</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
              <!-- This is the appetizer form -->
              <form>
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="inputNewLabel">Name</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="addNewAppetizer" name="appName" placeholder="What is the name of this appetizer?">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="inputNewLabel">Description</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="addNewAppDesc" name="appDesc" placeholder="Share details about your appetizer.">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="inputNewLabel">Add Photo</label>
                      <input type="file" id="addNewAppPic" name="appPic">
                      <p class="help-block">Upload a photo of your appetizer.</p>
                  </div>
              </form>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="submitApp">Submit Appetizer</button>
          </div>
        </div>
```

My appetizerForm.js for this specific html feature:

```
// client/views/forms/appetizerForm.js

Template.appetizerForm.events({
    'submitApp': function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var appetizer = {
            name: $(e.target).find('[name=appName]').val(),
            description: $(e.target).find('[name=appDesc]'),
            photo: $(e.target).find('[name=appPic]').val()
        }

        appetizer._id = Appetizers.insert(appetizer);
        Router.go('/', appetizer);
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with meteor so I don't get how it hooks up events - submitApp is only a button value, normally you would add an event listener on the form itself. I recommend for accessibility you put the button inside the form so that the enter key works for submitting etc

Comment: @DominicTobias Ah! Good catch. Thank you. That helped solve one piece of the puzzle... The modal now clears upon submission, but the data still isn't injected properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your event map syntax is wrong, it must be `eventType cssSelector`.

```
Template.appetizerForm.events({
  "submit form": function(event, template) {
    event.preventDefault();
    [...]
    template.$(".modal").modal("hide");
  }
});
```

If you want the modal to close upon form submission, use the jQuery plugin syntax to call the hide method on the modal.

Comment: Might be better to listen on the form element itself, so that return key submission is captured too